# React-native useContext returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to learn react and stuck at useContext. I have tried to export Provider and also change value data from provider but still it is returning undefined !
My Context

```
import React from 'react';

const BlogContext = React.createContext();

export const BlogProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const blogPosts = [
        { title: "Blog Post #1" },
        { title: "Blog Post #2" }
    ];

    return (
        <BlogContext.Provider value={blogPosts}>
            {children}
        </BlogContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default BlogContext;
```

My Screen

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { BlogContext } from '../context/BlogContext';

const IndexScreen = () => {
    const blogPosts = useContext(BlogContext);
    console.log(blogPosts);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Index Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default IndexScreen;
```

Comment: You are missing the `BlogContext.Consumer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you use `export const ...` You import it with curly brackets `{ }`
- If you used `export default ...` You should import **without** the curly brackets.

So you have mixed it:

```js
// just export the context
export const BlogContext = createContext()

const BlogProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const blogPosts = [...]

  return (
    <BlogContext.Provider value={blogPosts}>
      {children}
    </BlogContext.Provider>
  )
}
// export default the component
export default BlogProvider
```

Second, You need to **Wrap** your App with your `BlogProvider` component:

```js
// App.js
import React from "react"
import BlogProvider from "./context/AppContext" 
import IndexScreen from "./screens/IndexScreen"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BlogProvider>
      <IndexScreen />
      // More screens...
    </BlogProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is a working [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-usecontext-mh4tr) example.